# Nginx Wildcards and Subdomains with Certbot

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, certbot, wildcard

I want to achieve a scenario where I have 2 nodejs application running on localhost:3000 (dev) and localhost:5000 (staging). I also created 3 certificates and copied below.

With the config file I've copied below;

- *.dev.domain.app should go to dev (currently I have SSL problem, not sure where it is redirecting)
- *.domain.app (except for dev) should go to prod (kubi.domain.app going to dev instead of prod)
- dev.domain.app should go to dev, works fine with SSL
- domain.app should go to prod, works fine

here are the certificates

```
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: dev.domain.app
    Serial Number: [REDUCTED]
    Key Type: ECDSA
    Domains: dev.domain.app
    Expiry Date: 2024-06-30 11:42:50+00:00 (VALID: 87 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.app/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.domain.app/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain.app-0001
    Serial Number: [REDUCTED]
    Key Type: ECDSA
    Domains: *.domain.app
    Expiry Date: 2024-07-03 09:02:28+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app-0001/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app-0001/privkey.pem
  Certificate Name: domain.app
    Serial Number: [REDUCTED]
    Key Type: ECDSA
    Domains: domain.app
    Expiry Date: 2024-07-03 08:44:45+00:00 (VALID: 89 days)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app/privkey.pem
```

the configurationfile

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.dev\.domain\.app$;
    # should redirect dev

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; # Redirect to Node.js app on port 3000
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain\.app$;

    location / {
        if ($subdomain = "dev") {
            # should redirect dev
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000$request_uri;
            break;
        }
        # should redirect prod
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000$request_uri;
        break;
    }
}

server {
    server_name domain.app;
    # should redirect prod

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; # Redirect to Node.js app on port 3000
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    # should redirect prod
    if ($host = domain.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name domain.app;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome! Have you had a chance to read the manual? I just wanted to let you know that creating wildcard subdomains in nginx is not difficult. Each server can present either one name or multiple. To create a wildcard subdomain, use the following format: `servername *.sub.domain.app`. If you haven't already, please check out the nginx manual about `server_name` for more information. Additionally, you'll need to create either a wildcard certificate for your domain or single certificates for each subdomain. I hope this helps! [nginx manual](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Comment: so, this became a regex problem now. I want to match all of the *.domain.app to redirect Application 1 except for dev.domain.app. I want all *.dev.domain.app + dev.domain.app to redirect Application 2

Comment: @djdomi any change you can check my code? I updated and it works fine with x.domain.app, domain.app, dev.domain.app but it's not capturing x.dev.domain.app. Is there any A record or anything related with domain settings maybe?

Comment: OK. I could manage to solve the issue by adding *.dev A record. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

While certbot's integration with nginx and apache is quite impressive (IMHO) it doesn't always work as you might expect with more complex sites. IMHO, its a better idea to just use `certbot --certonly` and maintain the config files yourself if you've get anything more complex than one certificate for each vhost.

> Do I also need to create 2 more certs for *.dev.domain and *.domain?

No, you only need 2 wildcard certificates.

The default behaviour with certbot is to verify the identity of the host requesting a certificate is that certbot agrees a secret with the LetsEncrypt service, then stores that on the local webserver. If LetsEncrypt can successfully retrieve the secret it will sign the certificate. This is the HTTP-01 challenge. But that's not going to work for wildcard domains. The solution is to use the DNS-01 challenge mechanism. Here the secret is stored as a DNS record - proving you own the entire DNS zone.

But this is where things get a bit more murky. While there are standard protocols for updating DNS zone files not all providers implement these. Some of the non-standard APIs are supported in Certbot.

Note that wildcard certificates don't usually cover subdomains (i.e. *.*.domain). IIRC LetsEncrypt certs don't.

Comment: certbot certonly --manual -d *.domain.app -d domain.app --agree-tos --manual-public-ip-logging-ok --preferred-challenges dns-01 --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --rsa-key-size 4096
like this?